# How to sort a linked list and remove any duplicate

Tags: java

I have a method that takes in two linked lists and prints out a new linked list which is the two incoming lists combined. I wanna know how to sort the final list and remove the duplicates. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
public static IntNode method(IntNode head1, IntNode head2){

   // create a new list that will hold the two incoming lists
   IntNode new_head = new IntNode(0, null); 
   IntNode new_node = new_head;

   for(; head1 != null; head1 = head1.link) {
       new_node.link = new IntNode(head1.data, null);
       new_node = new_node.link;
   }

   for(; head2 != null; head2 = head2.link) {
       new_node.link = new IntNode(head2.data, null);
       new_node = new_node.link;
   }

   return new_head.link;
}
```

Comment: How to sort is a *very* broad topic. Please search the web for sorting algorithms, then implement one of them. Or use `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()`. Voting to close as **"too broad"**.

Comment: You can't use Collections.sort() with nodes

Comment: Correct you cannot sort your nodes directly with `Collections.sort()`. But you _could_ make a `Collection`, an `ArrayList`, say, from the nodes' data and then apply `Collections.sort()` to that.

Comment: @KevinAnderson i'm not following. Can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Hang on a moment, I'll write an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd do is write a method, if you don't already have one, to insert a node into a list:

```
public static IntNode insertNode(IntNode head, IntNode node)
{
    node.link = null;
    if (head == null) {
        return node;
    }
    IntNode root = head;
    while (root.link != null) {
        root = root.link;
    }
    root.link = node;
    return head;
}
```

Then, your merge-and-remove-duplicates routine would be something like this:

```
public static IntNode method(IntNode head1, IntNode head2)
{

    List<Integer> sort = new ArrayList<>();

    for (IntNode n = head1; n != null; n = n.link) {
        sort.add(n.data);
    }
    for (IntNode n = head2; n != null; n = n.link) {
        sort.add(n.data);
    }

    Collections.sort(sort);

    // run though sorted list, removing adjacent duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < sort.size(); ++i) {
        if (i > 0 && sort.get(i) == sort.get(i - 1)) {
            sort.remove(i);
        }
    }

    // Now put the sorted, unduplicated numbers into a new list of IntNodes
    IntNode new_head = null;
    for (int data : sort) {
        IntNode newNode = new IntNode(data, null);
        new_head = insertNode(new_head, newNode);
    }
    return new_head;
}
```